# plone - While in an edit form, what can cause portal catalog to fail in a source object for an autocomplete choice field?

Tags: python, plone, plone-5.x

I have a source object for a choice field that is an autocomplete widget and it relies on using portal catalog to find content based on the value passed in by the user.  Unfortunately, while viewing an Edit form, the portal_catalog sometimes returns 0 results where it should be returning 1 result.

The function that should be returning 1 result is 'getTerm'.  I did a print statement to see how many results it gets and to make sure the value being passed in is what the term's value should be.  My print statement shows the value passed in is always the one that should be, but it doesn't always find the result.  I am not sure why this is 'failing', when it works in the Add Form.

My Interface:

```
class IMyContentType(model.Schema):

    organization = schema.Choice(title='',
                                 source=Organizations(),
                                )
```

My object source:

```
class OrganizationsSource(object):
    implements(IQuerySource)

    def __init__(self,context):
        self.context = context

    def queryOrganizations(self,value):
        catalog = api.portal.get_tool(name='portal_catalog')
        brains = catalog.evalAdvancedQuery(
               AdvancedQuery.MatchRegexp('portal_type','Organization') &
               AdvancedQuery.MatchRegexp('Title',value+"*")
             )
        return [i.Title for i in brains]

    def __contains__(self,value):
        q = self.queryOrganizations(value)
        if len(q) > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def getTerm(self, value):
        q = self.queryOrganizations(value)
        #Where I check to see if it should be working
        #the value passed in is the one that should be
        print value, len(q)
        return SimpleTerm(title=q[0],value=q[0])

    def getTermByToken(self,token):
        return self.getTerm(token)

    def search(self,query_string):
        q = self.queryOrganizations(query_string)
        return [SimpleTerm(title=v,value=v,token=v) for v in q]

class Organizations(object):
    implements(IContextSourceBinder)

    def __init__(self):
        self.context = self

    def __call__(self, context):
        return OrganizationsSource(context)
```

Is this approach possible at all?  Is there a different catalog I should be using?

I also tried in the getTerm function a simple searchResults instead of evalAdvancedQuery:

```
def getTerm(self,value):
    catalog = api.portal.get_tool(name='portal_catalog')
    brains = catalog.searchResults({'portal_type':'Organization',
                                   'Title':value,
                                 })
    return SimpleTerm(title=brains[0]['Title'],
                      value=brains[0]['Title'],
                  )
```

I was getting the same issue.

I am using Plone 5.1.

Comment: Please ask in our forum, https://community.plone.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i would recommend you to use the ZCatalog and not AdvancedQuery.
For what you are doing there is no reason to use AdvancedQuery.
Just use the normal catalog thru the plone.api https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone.api/docs/content.html#find-content-objects
Also make sure the user has the needed permissions to see the objects you are searching for.

Example:

```
from plone import api

def query_organizations(self, search_term):
    search_term = search_term and search_term + '*' or ''
    documents = api.content.find(
        portal_type='Organization',
        Title=search_term,
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I wasn't too sure how to query partial search.  I replaced the advanced query with your method and unfortunately, I'm getting the same results.  Since the user is sometimes getting results, I'm not sure if its a permissions issue, unless the user (even administrator) is randomly being denied access?

Comment: Actually querying seems to fail when the user first clicks on the text field to enter a value, where getTerm is triggered.  When getTerm is called other times, it seems to work.

Comment: Like you suggested, it must be a permissions issue.  I tried using unrestrictedSearchResults: catalog.unrestrictedSearchResults({'portal_type':'Organization','Title':search_term}) and it returned me the term.

Comment: Hm, the same user should have the same permissions in the same context. Maybe your the pdb to step into this and find out if you are actually the same user and have the same permissions all the time. plone.api is your fried to get this informations. It is possible that you are in a diffenrent context if you only have local roles/permissions that matters. There might be also a diffenrence between add and edit form ;).